# inline keyword for templates

Tags: c++

This code will be placed in a header file:

```
template<typename TTT>
inline Permutation<TTT> operator * (const Cycle<TTT>& cy, const Permutation<TTT>& p)
{
    return Permutation<TTT>(cy)*p;
}
```

Is `inline` necessary to avoid a linker error?

If this function is not a template and the header file is used in more than one .cpp file, `inline` is necessary to avoid a liker error complaining about multiple definitions for a function. It seems linker ignores this for templates.

Comment: Do you know include guards (ifdef-define or pragma once)? Don´t make strange workarounds

Comment: I'm talking about a linker error. So the codes are compiled but not linked.

Comment: I know. But, leaving "template or not" aside, your problem is a usual beginner error. Doesn´t matter if template or not. That´s why i´m asking, if i should explain this or something more difficult.

Comment: Yes templates are special and have to be visible to get instantiated. You can omit the inline if you don't want it.

Comment: @deviantfan No, this is completely unrelated to include guards.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Well, i could´ve misunderstood a "what does the standard say and why" etc. as "why my code a won´t link, only part b"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is `inline` necessary to avoid a linker error?

On a function template, no. Templates, like inline functions, are subject to a more relaxed One Definition Rule which allows multiple definitions - as long as the definitions are identical and in separate translation units.

As you say, `inline` would be necessary if you wanted to define a non-template function in a header; non-inline functions are subject to a more strict One Definition Rule, and can only have one definition in a program.

For the gory details, this is specified by C++11 3.2/5:

> There can be more than one definition of a class type, **inline function** with
>   external linkage, class template, non-static **function template**, static data member
>   of a class template, member function of a class template, or template specialization for
>   which some template parameters are not specified in a program provided that each definition
>   appears in a different translation unit, and provided the definitions satisfy the following requirements.

(The "following requirements" basically say that the definitions must be identical).

Answer (score 1):

Consider that a template function (or function template if you prefer) is not a function at all.  It is rather a recipe to create a function.  The actual function is only created when and where the template is instantiated.  So you do not need the `inline` keyword here, because template functions will not result in multiple-definition linker errors because they are not actually defined (from the linker's perspective) until they are used.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Mike Seymour's answer -- the paragraph (3.2/5) he cites in in the Standard refers to a concept called ["vague linkage"](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Vague-Linkage.html#Vague-Linkage).  Basically, it's a way of saying "we need this to exist *somewhere* in the resulting binary, but we don't have a clear-cut home for it in any specific object file we're emitting."  On modern platforms (Windows, ELF systems such as Linux, and OS X), this is implemented using a mechanism known as COMDAT support that allows the compiler to simply generate the instantiations and other vague linkage items (vtables, typeinfos, and inline function bodies) as-needed -- the linker then is free to throw out the duplicates:

> When used with GNU ld version 2.8 or later on an ELF system such as GNU/Linux or Solaris > 2, or on Microsoft Windows, duplicate copies of these constructs will be discarded at 
>   link time. This is known as COMDAT support.

This is discussed in more detail in the [GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Template-Instantiation.html#Template-Instantiation) (quote snipped as the Cfront model is irrelevant for modern compilers):

> C++ templates are the first language feature to require more intelligence from the 
>   environment than one usually finds on a UNIX system. Somehow the compiler and linker 
>   have to make sure that each template instance occurs exactly once in the executable if 
>   it is needed, and not at all otherwise. There are two basic approaches to this problem, 
>   which are referred to as the Borland model and the Cfront model.
>
> Borland model
>
> Borland C++ solved the template instantiation problem by adding the code equivalent 
>   of common blocks to their linker; the compiler emits template instances in each 
>   translation unit that uses them, and the linker collapses them together. The advantage 
>   of this model is that the linker only has to consider the object files themselves; there 
>   is no external complexity to worry about. This disadvantage is that compilation time is 
>   increased because the template code is being compiled repeatedly. Code written for this 
>   model tends to include definitions of all templates in the header file, since they must 
>   be seen to be instantiated.